# Adapting output directory layout for SBT 0.13.5

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I want to introduce SBT into an existing, mainly JAVA based project which until now uses ant as build tool.
The directory layout is not fully conforming to maven style, especially for the output paths.
The built JAR files should be written not in the "target/" directory, but to a directory named "dist/", where  is the major version of the currently used JAVA SDK (i.e. 1.7 for JAVA 7, 1.8 for JAVA 8 etc.).
This is needed because some JAVA sources are actually major version specific, and the built JAR files should reflect that (a client using JAVA 7 should get the JARs from dist/1.7, one using JAVA 8 those from dist/1.8 ... etc.).
On the other hand the scala version is irrelevant for this project (an application, mainly java), because we control the scala version used here.

How can this be done? I found no way yet to switch the path of the built jar files from "target/" to at least "dist" (and how to calculated parts of this path dynamically?)

Comment: For linux/macos you can create symbolic link `ln -s target dist`

Answer (score 0):

My hint is **Redefine crossTarget**:

```scala
def ProjectName(name: String, path: String) = 
     Project(name, file(path)).settings(
           crossTarget := file(sourceDirectory.value.getAbsolutePath) / "dist" / scalaVersion.value)
```

And then:

```scala
lazy val root := ProjectName("root",".")//other settings

lazy val subProject := ProjectName("subProject","subProject")//other settings
```

Comment: Hm, may try it - but it would have to be System.getProperty(java.vm.specification) instead of scalaVersion - the latter is fixed by ukas by us, but we may need to produce our software for different JVM versions.